# Javascript JSON- How to map on multiple object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I try to display a value, from a local json file, of mutiple objects here the "groundName". My purpose is to  map on mutiple objects at once so I can avoid to rewrite object's name to access the value I need. I did not manage to find answer to this specific issue, so I came here to ask.

Here by writting the object's name I do retrieve the value I want.

```js
import  { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import grounds from './../../UballersGroundsData.json';

export default function Groundlist() {
    const [groundNames, setgroundNames] = useState([grounds]);

    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Hello world!</h1> 
            <ul>
                {groundNames.map(([index]) => (
                    <li key={(index.ground1.groundId)}>{index.ground1.groundName}</li>
                    ))}

                  
                   

            </ul>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Here a part of the .json file

```json
{
  "ground1":{
    "groundId": "2",
    "address": "77-101 Quai Branly, Paris, France",
    "city": "Paris",
    "country": "France",
    "groundName": "Bir-Hakeim",
  },
  "ground2":{
    "groundId": "26585",
    "address": "1 Rue du Petit Cardinal, Bordeaux, France",
    "city": "Bordeaux",
    "country": "France",
    "groundName": "1 Rue du Petit Cardinal"
  }
}
```

Thank you for you're help ! =D

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    {
         Object.values(groundNames).map((object) => (
             let obj = groundNames[object];
             <li key={(obj.groundId)}>{obj.groundName}</li>
         ))
    }
</ul>
```

Try the above code

Comment: Thank you but it dont recognize the " let " variable.